# Custom user permissions for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Django application which will be periodically uploading things to S3. I figured that it'd be easy enough to store the S3 key and secret in my settings file:

```
S3_KEY = "whateverkeything"
S3_SECRET = "mykeysecret"
```

Then, considering security and the idea of limiting permissions whenever applicable, reconsidered this approach. My application will only ever need to GET and PUT/POST objects, never DELETE objects, never create nor DELETE buckets, etc. Plus, if someone got access to my AWS key and secret, they could potentially start 100 massive EC2 instances, running me into a ton of debt.

Is there a way to limit access and create a new "user" for S3 which would only have the described permissions? Or am I being too paranoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely should create a user with only the necessary permissions. It's easy to do with IAM (Identity and Access Management). You can create a new user on your existing AWS account (easiest to do from the AWS console) and then give it just the minimal permissions it needs. That way, if the credentials are somehow compromised, the scope of damage is limited.

Another option is to assign your server an IAM role, but I don't know if the PHP tools will work with a role.

Assigning S3 permissions is pretty easy using the console's policy editor. You just select the specific operations (GET object and PUT object, it seems) and give the "ARN" of the resources to apply it to. If your bucket is named "mybucket", the ARN would be `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*` . If you need to list the resources in the bucket, too, you would add a second policy for List Bucket with an ARN of `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket` (no trailing slash or asterisk).

Information about IAM users and roles is available in the [IAM User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html).